# why are this.props.classes undefined in Higher order component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, higher-order-components

[image: PopupTest (having the material style)][image: Here is the background.js][image: this is the HOC]this.props.classes are "undefined" when used in HOC; whereas if we don't render it via HOC it works just fine. i am not able to figure out what is wrong! Thank you in advance!

i have this simple component  that works with material and shows all the styles but asap i use it within a higher order component to render even passing the props to them in HOC. but this.props.classes are coming undefined. i have attached some screen shots of hoc PopUpComponent,  [image]

this is the hoc..res both our just plain components trying
const PopUpComponent= OriginalComponent=>{
class NewComponent extends React.Component{

```
  render(){
    console.log(this.props,'hwere df')
    return (
      <div>
        <span>in the hoc</span>
        <PopupTest {...this.props} />

        <OriginalComponent {...this.props}/>


      </div>

          )
  }
}
return NewComponent
```